# Agiletoolkit-bundle 4.3 installation

Tags: atk4

i want to try new atk4 4.3 version. I know its still in development, but my hands itch ;)

So i found this, and i thought this is good bundle to start with?
https://github.com/atk4/agiletoolkit-bundle

I cloned it and used ./update.sh, but i get this error:

```
Cloning failed using an ssh key for authentication, enter your GitHub credentials to access private repos
The credentials will be swapped for an OAuth token stored in C:/Users/wechta/AppData/Roaming/Composer/config.json, your password will not be stored
To revoke access to this token you can visit https://github.com/settings/applications
```

But if i remove this lines from composer.json it gets to the end:

```
"rvadym\/languages":"dev-master",
"rvadym\/x_tinymce":"dev-master",
"rvadym\/blog":"dev-master",
```

is this the right package to start playing with atk4 3.4, or what im doing wrong? im using all this stuff the first time on windows, so there is a lot of not knowing.. Thank for help!

Comment: I hope Romans will have time to answer, but as far as I know, he don't like Windows to much :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bundle is currently not fully available through GIT. If you do want to follow our internal development, then:

http://www4.agiletoolkit.org/

and click download. You can also check periodically:

http://www4.agiletoolkit.org/changes

Comment: Thanks, looks nice :)

Comment: Hi, 4.3 version is looking very nice, im migrating my project to new version already. I know its way to soon, but it is local project anyway... I know there are no documentation yet, but im really curious how to create new forms, like the 'Stacked Compact Form' from here: http://css.agiletoolkit.org/. Any directions very much appreciated. :)

Comment: Here is a comprehensive guide: https://github.com/atk4/docs/blob/master/user-interface/form/styling-and-layouts.md

Comment: hi, i found some bugs .. is there any bugtracer or how dows one report them? Thnx.

Comment: Documentation on  new forms have migrated here: http://book.agiletoolkit.org/views/form/layout.html

Comment: Nice documentation :) But the bug is still there, with the upload form.. https://github.com/atk4/atk4/issues/549